# Solving a set of ODE with conditional statement

Tags: python, matplotlib, if-statement, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a set of differential equations with Python. Basically, I want to plot the figure below:

[image: Graph that I want to generate]

This is a graph that shows how the concentration of nutrients (Am) and phytoplankton (Phy) changes with time.
The Python code that I have to plot both variables as function of time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

# parameters
dil = 0.2            
har_f = 20           
har_pc = 0.95       
ext_Am = 100
umax_Phy = 0.693
kAm_Phy = 14
t0 = 0           
tf = 100             
ns = 200
dt = (tf-t0)/(ns-1)

params = [dil, har_f, har_pc, ext_Am, umax_Phy, kAm_Phy, t0, tf, ns, dt]

def odes(t,x):
    dx = [0,0]
    har_dil = 0

    if t > 0 and t % har_f == 0:
        har_dil = har_pc/dt
    else:
        har_dil = 0
      
    time_dil = params[0] + har_dil
    in_Am = params[3] * time_dil
    u_Phy = params[4]*x[0]/(x[0]+params[5])
    gro_Phy = u_Phy * x[1]
    out_Am = x[0] * time_dil
    out_Phy = x[1] * time_dil
    dx[0] = in_Am - out_Am - gro_Phy
    dx[1] = gro_Phy - out_Phy

    return dx

# initial conditions:
x0 = [99,1]

# declare a time vector(time window)
tspan = (0,100)

# solving the set of ODEs
sol = solve_ivp(odes,tspan,x0)

fig1,axs_lst = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,squeeze=False)

axs_lst[0,0].plot(sol.t,sol.y[0, :],'-',color='red',label='Am')
axs_lst[0,0].plot(sol.t,sol.y[1, :],color='green',label='Phy')
axs_lst[0,0].legend(loc='best',frameon=True,edgecolor='black',fancybox=False)
axs_lst[0,0].set_xlabel('Time [day]',size='12')
axs_lst[0,0].set_ylabel('Concentration [$g\:biomass\:m^{-3}$]',size='12')
axs_lst[0,0].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', direction='in')
axs_lst[0,0].grid(True)
```

However the graph that is generated is shown below:
[image: Graph generated by the code]

As you can see, the concentration of nutrients does not decrease as it should because the value of the variable har_dil accounted is only the final value of the conditional statement. I would appreciate if someone could please help me with a strategy to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
    if t == 0:
        har_dil = 0
    elif t > 0 and t % har_f == 0:
        har_dil = har_pc/dt
    else:
        har_dil = 0
        
    har_dil = 0
```

Ok, couple of things going on there.

(1.) You went to some trouble to compute `har_dil`,
and then you *unconditionally* zero it.
That can't possibly be what you intended.
Recommend you break out the `if` as a helper function,
and unconditionally assign the result of that function.

(2.) The `t % har_f == 0` expression is apparently
trying to inject some periodicity, as seen in your first figure.
Good.
But, fair warning, asking if a
[FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)
quantity is exactly equal to zero is rather hit-or-miss.
Recommend that you either put `int(t)` into that expression,
or else ask if the modulo result is "close to" zero.
That is, pick a small epsilon and ask if `abs(t % har_f) < epsilon`.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, that was not intended. Actually the line har_dil = 0 should be written before the if-statement, because this is the usual value, except when time is a multiple of 20 (har_f = 20). I tried to use abs(t % har_f) < epsilon, as you suggested, but the graph generated was still the same. I have also updated the code, so that the line har_dil = 0 is before the conditional statement.

Comment: Changes of the ODE in one point do not change the exact solution, the numerical solver might be driven to small step sizes, but might miss the point or the small interval around it completely. It is better to just stop the integration at such points, make the intended changes to the parameters or state vector  and resume integration until the next interesting time.